# What is the Difference between Regex `[]*` and `[]+`?

Tags: regular-expression

I started learning regex recently. I know that `*` modifier means `match 0 or more times` while `+` modifier means match `1 or more times`.

However when you use these modifiers with square brackets, how will the code get parsed? It seems to me that using square brackets would equalize the `+` and `*`.

For example: What is the difference between `[\w\s,:]+` and `[\w\s,:]*`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is exactly that you wrote. The characters in the set may occur once to multiple times with + and may also not occur at all with * .

Comment: so `[...|]+` will be equal to `[...]*`?

Comment: Ummm ... no. [] defines a character class. Adding a pipe symbol to that won't do what you think it does. It's NOT grouping. Also three dots inside [] don't make sense. They're literals in there.

Comment: @C Rags: Assuming your dots stand for any set of characters. No, they are not the same. The left one will match any non-empty sequence of those characters plus the pipe character, while the right one will only match sequences of those characters in any amount including zero.

Comment: @CRags, no, but `([...]+|)` will be equal to `[...]*`

Comment: Also, `[abc][abc]*`, `[abc]*[abc]`, and `[abc]+` are all equivalent.